# Trouble replacing text in jQTouch

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I have the following block of code in a jQTouch app I'm working on:

```
<div class="info">
   <div id="MyValue">Sample Text</div>
</div>

<p onclick="ResetValue();">
   Reset
</p>
```

When writing my ResetValue method, the following jQuery syntax does not work:

```
$("MyValue").html("Changed Text");
```

However, if I use the "classic" method, the following text does work:

```
var value_block = document.getElementById("MyValue");
value_block.innerHTML = "Changed Text";
```

Is there something I'm missing with jQTouch or jQuery in general that is preventing the jQuery style code from working?

*Note: I've also tried "wiring up" the click event to the paragraph (instead of using onclick directly in the tag) and get the same result.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `#` in the selector. It should be

```
$("#MyValue").html("Changed Text");
```

[Some docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) on selecting a div based on id in jQuery

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NuMLj/) of how I would do it.

Comment: It's always something small like that. Works like a charm. Thanks!